# Splunk Java API connect with SSO

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, splunk

I have to create a Java application that can fetch results from Splunk searches. I am able to do it easily with my local installation of Splunk using methods given in tutorials (Basic Authentication). But when I use the same code with my organization's Splunk, the connection request is timed out.

My organization's Splunk server is accessible only through SingleSignOn (SSO).
How do I connect with the Splunk server with the Java API?

I am listing my code which worked well for local installation (Basic Authentication).

```
serviceArgs loginArgs = new ServiceArgs();
    loginArgs.setUsername("My_Uname");
    loginArgs.setPassword("My_Pass");
    loginArgs.setHost("localhost");
    loginArgs.setPort(8089);
    Service service = Service.connect(loginArgs);
```

Comment: Request timeout usually means that you don't have the correct host / port (or it's not accessible to you due to ACLs). Also Splunk SSO only applies to the web interface, not the API. See also: [Splunk's docs on SSO](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Security/HowSplunkSSOworks)

Answer (score 1):

com.splunk.Service class has a login method which is called when Service.connect(loginArgs) method is called.Login method has below line:

```
ResponseMessage response = post("/services/auth/login", args);
```

the path `http://<<yourhost>>/services/auth/login` might be invalid. Overriding com.splunk.Service class by our own implementation solves the problem.